# How to write Table Driven Development test?

Tags: unit-testing, go, tdd

I am trying to write TDD for the following code. But, I cant able to cover 100% coverage in my test code. Can anyone give me the correct code to cover my test?

The following codes are used to connect my Database

```
func Dbconn() (*sql.DB, error) {

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres:root@tcp(localhost:5432)/customer_complaints?multistatements=true")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return db, nil
}
```

The following codes are my test case
package models

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    "reflect"
    "testing"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func TestDbconn(t *testing.T) {
    db, _ := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres:root@tcp(localhost:5432)/customer_complaints?multistatements=true")
    tests := []struct {
        name    string
        want    *sql.DB
        wantErr bool
    }{
        {
            name:    "Success connection",
            want:    db,
            wantErr: false,
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            got, err := Dbconn()
            if (err != nil) != tt.wantErr {
                t.Errorf("Dbconn() error = %v, wantErr %v", err, tt.wantErr)
                return
            }
            if !reflect.DeepEqual(got, tt.want) {
                t.Errorf("Dbconn() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

If I run my test, it will cover only 75%.
And also giving me error like this

```
     go test -v --cover
      === RUN   TestDbconn
      === RUN   TestDbconn/Success_connection
      db_test.go:32: Dbconn() = &{{{} {} 0} {postgres:root@tcp(localhost:5432)/customer_complaints?multistatements=true 0x8d4730} {{} {} 0} {0 0} [] map[] 0 0 0xc0000824e0 false map[] map[] 0 0 0 0 <nil> 0 0 0 0 0x50f1a0}, want &{{{} {} 0} {postgres:root@tcp(localhost:5432)/customer_complaints?multistatements=true 0x8d4730} {{} {} 0} {0 0} [] map[] 0 0 0xc000082420 false map[] map[] 0 0 0 0 <nil> 0 0 0 0 0x50f1a0}
--- FAIL: TestDbconn (0.00s)
    --- FAIL: TestDbconn/Success_connection (0.00s)
        coverage: 75.0% of statements exit status 1
```

Comment: run the below two command, in html command you can see which branch of statements you are missing.  `go test -coverprofile=output_filename

go tool cover -html=output_filename`

Comment: Thank you. Can you give me the replaceable code for my test case?

Comment: Isn't it there is no scenario for making `Dbconn` return error?